# Set the intervals of the ticks

Tags: ticks, frame

I have a list of data:

```
{{{11, 0.364743}}, {{16, 0.00009956}}, {{21, 1.47878*10^-8}}, {{26, 
   9.73444*10^-13}}, {{31, 1.01608*10^-12}}, {{36, 1.99663*10^-12}}}
```

I want to plot this in a frame chart but setting the axes like this way:

[image]

The interval of the "y frame" has to be something like `1/100`.
By the way, my data has to be about the black curve.

Comment: If Ticks doesn’t do what you need, can you include your code. Also, when you say the y interval should be something like 1/10, do you mean as opposed to the 1/100 in the picture?

Comment: You are right, is 1/100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {{{11, 0.364743}}, {{16, 0.00009956}}, {{21, 
1.47878*10^-8}}, {{26, 9.73444*10^-13}}, {{31, 
1.01608*10^-12}}, {{36, 1.99663*10^-12}}}
```

Next make logarithmic plot with only major y-ticks:

```
ListPlot[MapAt[Log, data, {All, 1, 2}], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> 
{{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][##, {10}] &, 
Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}][##, {10}] &}, {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

I used `ListPlot` and map `Log` to the `data` by hand to simplify using `ScaledTicks`. Default parameter that regulates number of major ticks is `{6}`, I used `{10}` to increase number of ticks.